# How to update my users of the version without using a webservices

Tags: android

I have made a simple android application and it does not have any web services. The Application is present in the Playstore. Suppose If I have fixed a bug in it and I want the users of the application update to the newer one. How can I do this? Please help me out!!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Application updates depend on play store and the settings of the user on his/her device.

Short answer: without a web service, i don't think its possible to do that.

Comment: Sorry for being naive, but I heard it like this...

Suppose if your version is 1.0(With bugs)
Fix Bugs, Change the versioncode in Manifest to 2.0 and upload on playstore..

Comment: That is the default way of letting the play store know that you are upgrading the app with something new :) , once you do that, play store updates the users for the change and its download. This is also combined with the settings on the device of the user, whether automatic updates have been allowed or not